# What explains this feature of measurable cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

(1) I am searching for a non-technical explanation linking one or more of the properties a measurable cardinal has by definition with that fact that there is no second-order property which holds for the first time at a measurable cardinal.

For example, the definition that looks most promising is the one in terms of elementary embeddings: $\kappa$ is measurable if it is the critical point of a non-trivial elementary embedding of the universe V into a transitive class M.

However, the embedding only guarantees a mapping of $first$-order formulas, so I can't see how second-order reflection properties could enter the picture.

(2) Is a measurable the smallest of the large cardinals with this property?

Comment: I'm not a specialist but I feel that this question would deserve more than one sentence.

Comment: What is non-technical to you? The characterization of measurable cardinals via elementary embeddings gives this property immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. You should be able to see easily that if $M$ is transitive and $j\!:V\to M$ is elementary with critical point $\kappa$ then every subset of $V_\kappa$ is in $M$, and therefore $V_{\kappa+1}^M=V_{\kappa+1}$. This gives the reflection you are after.

Comment: Anyway, no, measurables are far from being first with this indescribability property. This is a classical result of Vaught.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that if $j\colon V\to M$ is an elementary embedding with critical point $\kappa$, then $\mathcal P(\kappa)^V=\mathcal P(\kappa)^M$. They have the same power sets.

Now. A second-order property of $\kappa$, in fact of $V_\kappa$, is really just a first-order property when you have the entire power set. And the fact $V_{\kappa+1}=M_{\kappa+1}$, or $\mathcal P(\kappa)^V=\mathcal P(\kappa)^M$, means that the two models agree on the second-order properties of $\kappa$ and $V_\kappa$.

But now, being the least cardinal with a second-order property is a first-order property *in $V$*, so $j(\kappa)$ is the least one in $M$. But oh-uh, $V$ and $M$ agree on second-order properties of $\kappa$!

Comment: Should it be obvious why being the least cardinal with a second-order property is a first-order property in V?

Comment: Yes, because it's a property talking about $\mathcal P(\kappa)$. It's an object in $V$. So the truth of the structure $(\kappa,\mathcal P(\kappa),\in)$, or whatever, is a first-order statement in $V$. Just like how second-order logic is a first-order logic inside the universe of sets (so $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb N$ are unique up to isomorphism with their second-order theories).